# I am looking for a specific short story about space pirates and gods

Tags: story-identification

In the late 90's or early aughts I bought a scifi compilation that included an amazing story about a group of space pirates that try to take over a ship. This ship's crew behaves and looks like the Hindu gods. I won't spoil the ending, and that is all the information I have on it. Can anyone help identify this story?

In the end,

> the "gods" invite the pirates into the ship and defeat them after a sort of banquet. They go on with their travels, presumably to find other pirates to trap.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183216/name-of-a-short-story-from-a-years-best-sci-fi-collection (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

I am certain that this is the novellette ***[Guest Law](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?73008)*** by John C. Wright.  It first appeared in July 1997 in Volume 21 (No. 7) of *Asimov's Science Fiction*. It was reprinted in 1998 in a collection called *Year's Best SF 3* (published by HarperPrism), which is where you may have read it.

[image]

In the novellette, space pirates attempt to commandeer a ship that was initially believed to be derelict.  There is some debate amongst the pirates as to whether the derelict ship is a "religious ship".  The pirates discover that ship's crew is still aboard, and are then invited to the ship for a feast.

The ship's crew are not mentioned explicitly to have the appearance of "Hindu gods", but we do have the following passage:

> Here was the captain, floating at the focal point of an array of banners so that she looked like a **Boddhisattva** of Gaia in the center of a celestial rose.

Given the number of matching plot points and the time of publication, I suspect this is the work you are seeking.

Comment: @Anticool76: Please do let us know if this is correct.