# Space opera novella about a civilization that exists on huge space ships where higher-caste individuals have a second pair of hands in place of feet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-opera

Please help me identify a space opera novella about caste-based civilization that exists on huge space ships with no gravity in which higher-caste individuals have a second pair of hands in place of feet.

The plot of the story revolves around a stranger who comes onto one of these huge ships, on which the captain is like the emperor of a medieval country and the crew perform ritualized courtly functions.  The stranger is invited to a stately banquet that is described in minute detail. Due to the absence of gravity, the participants are arranged in a circle or oval with the captain at the head, higher than all the others.  The dishes are served in glass spheres which are arranged before each person in two rows that can be conveniently reached by the upper and lower hands of those who have the proper modifications.  The stranger is subjected to many small insults such as having a draft blow his dishes constantly out of position.  He appears to be harmless and powerless and the captain and others on the ship decide to kill him somehow (I don’t remember this part clearly).

Throughout the story, there are several references to a mythical creature (or god) that comes to ships disguised as a simple traveler and punishes those who do not render it the correct courtesies as demanded by the laws of hospitality.  For this reason, the captain and crew are cautious with the stranger, however, most disbelieve the myths and are too prideful to behave properly.  Predictably, the stranger is indeed this mythical creature and the story ends as he reveals himself in his full glory.

I read this many years ago in an anthology or science fiction magazine.  Sadly I do not remember any further details, but the story was beautifully written and has stayed with me all these years. I would be grateful to read it again.

Comment: "[Guest Law](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?73008)" by John C. Wright. It's a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183216/name-of-a-short-story-from-a-years-best-sci-fi-collection)

Comment: It's not your story, but Lois McMaster-Bujold's *Falling Free* has a similar setup of a large spaceship with (genetically engineered) "Quaddies" who are adapted for zero G and have hands in place of their feet. However, there is no medieval setup or prophecy. Instead, it's a social (getting the Quaddies their rights) and engineering (how to adapt the station for movement, and deal with damages) drama.

Comment: [Guest Law](https://archive.org/details/asimovsv21n07199707/page/n57/mode/2up) on archive.org

Comment: Thank you for the answer!